# conda is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, conda

I was updating pandas (on windows 7) using:

```
conda update pandas
```

accidentally I closed the command window while updating.
Now I can't start spyder and if I type conda in the command window I get:

```
"conda is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file"
```

if I type spyder --show=console I get

```
from PyQt5.Qtwidgets import * 
importerror: DLL load failed: The specific module could not be found
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I think you need to reinstall Anaconda because you broke it.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thanks, Do I have to unistall/cancel any file?

Comment: Since you broke conda, you probably need to remove by hand the directory where you installed Anaconda, after trying to uininstall it from the Control Panel. That should be enough, I think.

Comment: @gabboshow did you get it fixed yet?

Comment: Hi, yes I reinstalled anaconda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across the same problem today. I was trying to install it on Windows 10 (64-bit OS). I installed Anaconda (version 4.4.0) without adding Anaconda to my PATH environment variable.

The command `conda info` returned the same error:

```
 "conda is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file"
```

I uninstalled Anaconda and installed it again, this time by selecting **BOTH** the options in the installation instruction as shown:

[image]:

Now the command `conda info` works, returning relevant information pertaining to version, platform, etc.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: you dont need to reinstall :  go to the controlpanel\System\Advanced system settings\Environment Variables\Path then hit edit and add  your path to scripts eg: `C:Users\user_name\Anaconda3\Scripts`

Comment: In the installation instructions i've checked both the options and also have set the environment variables.But still i'm getting same error.unable to see jupyter notebook launch option.can you suggest me for the same?

Comment: @JinSnow :: Your solution worked for me but with little change in path "C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts". Note :: I am using anaconda3.

Comment: Anaconda instructions say adding the path is not advisable. Has anyone run into issues because of adding it to the path?

Answer (score 2):

Search pip in your system and set the location to your system environment variable. For example, for default setting, you may add following path: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts

Answer (score 2):

You can add anaconda to path in Windows with SETX PATH in CMD.exe. Find where Anaconda is installed (If you cannot remember where it was installed, open Anaconda prompt, and you will see the path to your anaconda)

- **Search Windows**

[image: Open Anaconda prompt]

- Path to your Anaconda

[image: patht to your conda]

We need both anaconda and its scripts. In CMD:

```
SETX PATH "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts;"
```

Close and open CMD, and all, if everything went well, will be working.

Answer (score 2):

> **"After 32-bit Anaconda installation ,Anaconda Navigator Not found Only Anaconda prompt is found"**

First install **Anaconda2-5.3.1-Windows-x86.exe**

https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86.exe

After this, open **Anaconda Prompt**

1.enter command  to check python installation ***where python***

```
(base) C:\Users\admin>where python
C:\Users\admin\Miniconda3\python.exe
```

2.enter command to check conda installation **where conda**

```
(base) C:\Users\admin>where conda
C:\Users\admin\Miniconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat
C:\Users\admin\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
```

3.enter command to find version ***conda   --version***

Inside the ***System Properties window***, go to the ***Advanced tab*** and click on ***Environment Variables***…

Select the ***Path variable*** and click the Edit button.
click the ***New button***. Then, add these two locations:

```
C:\Users\*YourUser*\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\*YourUser*\Anaconda3
```

4.After this steps ,add Command to install Anaconda Navigator

```
 conda install  anaconda-navigator
```

Now open the start menu ,you can found the anaconda navigator

## For further reference

https://appuals.com/fix-conda-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batch-file/

Answer (score 0):

Download the anaconda file in a different folder and install it from there.

Windows permission errors when installing from Favorites folder
Cause
The Windows Favorites folder has unusual permissions and may cause permission errors with installers of any software. If you try launching the installer from the Favorites folder you may see errors such as “Setup was unable to create the directory”, “Access is denied”, or “Error opening file for writing”.

Solution
Move the installer to a different folder and run the installer from the new folder.

Answer (score 0):

solution for **conda not recognized as a internal or external even after specifying path.**
try to **reinstall** the anaconda i.e., firstly uninstall the present installed one and again reinstall it. then make sure that u have checked the box which is not just me. click on **all users(requires admin privileges)** provide the access and then choose your folder or let it be as it is if your c drive has required space then checkbox for automatic path then install it. 
      after the installation check for anaconda prompt in search else go to command prompt then check out by typing **conda -version** it will show you the version.
install the packages. type **android-navigator** then enter to open the application then launch your required application.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, click on the start menu and search env, and select Edit for your account.

[image]

Double click on Path and for Anaconda add:

`C:Users\user_name\Anaconda3\Scripts`

for miniconda add:

`C:Users\user_name\miniconda3\Scripts`

click ok and close. You should be able to run conda after closing and reopening the `cmd` window.

Answer (score 0):

edit the environment variables through C:

> C:Users\user_name\Anaconda3\Scripts

install packages from following commands:
`CONDA_NO_PLUGINS=true conda install <package>`
it works for me
I installed tensorflow with the following command

> `conda --no-plugins install tensorflow`